# R sapply new evaluation of function for each incidence in array

Tags: r, arrays, tidyverse, substitution, evaluation

Thanks to lots of help, I've got an expression that substitutes the value from a rbinom into a vector, when certain conditions are met.  My problem is that it always substitutes the same value, i.e. does not do a new evaluation for each instance of the conditions being met.  I think I just need to wrap it in a sapply statement but haven't got the syntax correct. MWE:

```
arr1 <- c(8, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 4)
arr2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)

arr1
arr1[Reduce("&", list(arr1 == 2, arr2 ==1))] <- rbinom(1,1,0.5) * 2
arr1
arr1
[1] 8 2 5 0 3 0 0 0 8 0 4
```

I would have hoped that it changed some of the values but not others, so evaluated the result again for each instance.  Is this a good application of **purrr::modify2** ? Thx. J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you mean to use :

```
inds <- arr1 == 2 & arr2 == 1
arr1[inds] <- rbinom(sum(inds), 1, 0.5) * 2
```